# PHP array group for status condition

Tags: php, html, mysql, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have the following data I get back from mySQL:

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [list_id] = 2
            [price] => 10
            [tax_type] => custom
        )

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [list_id] = 2
        [price] => 10
        [tax_type] => freezone
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3
        [list_id] = 3
        [price] => 10
        [tax_type] => freezone        )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 4
        [list_id] = 3
        [price] => 10
        [tax_type] => custom        )
```

)

The data basically shows for example multiple purchases within one order (so for example, 3 purchases, with different product price/tax bands).

I can for example retrieve the prices as I'd like via:

```
foreach($array_data as $out) {
foreach($out as $inner) {
$sum['price'] += $inner->price;
        }
}
```

However I'm having difficulty in adding a condition, for example if I do:

```
if ($tax_type == "custom") {
                $sum['price'] += $inner->price;
                $tax_band = ($tax_rate / 100) * $inner->price;
                $tax band = round($tax_band, 2);
            } else { 
                $sum['price'] += $inner->price;
                $tax_band = ($tax_rate / 100) * $inner->price;
                $tax band = round($tax_band, 2); }
```

Works ok -- however I have a third scenario here -- if an array item contains both a custom / freezone status, it doesn't seem to work too well with my condition, as I'd like to iterate the array and work out the individual price tax bands, rather than set them all as one item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use elseif or switch statement.

[Php api control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

An example of elseif statement would be:

```
if ($tax_type == "custom") {

    //logic for custom

} 
elseif($tax_type == "freezone"){

    //logic for freezone

}
elseif($tax_type == "custom/freezone") { 

    //logic for custom/freezone

}
```

Comment: I do already have conditions -- the main thing here is when I try to pass:

    elseif($tax_type == "custom/freezone"

it's not doing anything with regards to the grouping -- i.e. it should apply the condition if both the statuses are found in the array.

Comment: In the example given you show three records, two with freezone and one with custom. What would the record returned be for the instance of both? Are there multiple indexes for each one? Are they concatenated together as a string value in the "tax_type" index?